# SecurityException for class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.DSTU4145$Mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring boot version **2.1.11**.After adding the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` in my `pom.xml`.I am getting the following error while running the application.

```
 "java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.DSTU4145$Mappings"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"
```

Answer (score 7):

It is because of some jar version incompatibility in the libraries to load, aka. jar-hell.
Try to exclude the group `org.bouncycastle`. You can specify the version also: `bcprov-jdk16`

For gradle:

```
implementation(group: 'aaa', name: 'bbb', version: '1.0.0') {
  exclude group: 'org.bouncycastle'
}
```

For maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>aaa</groupId>
        <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```